# How to compare a datetime from HTML (as a str) with a datetime in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web

I am using selenium to pull videos and I am trying to write something that checks to see if the datetime of when the video was posted was before the start of yesterday. I am running into trouble comparing the datetime I pulled from the video and yesterday.

```
    timeOfPost = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("").get_attribute("datetime")
    if(timeOfPost > yesterday):
        videoLinks.append(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("").get_attribute("src"))
```

How would I got about comparing the time of the post which is returned as a string and a datetime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the string date (taken from HTML) to a python date object and then compare it with the other object. For example:

```py
from datetime import date

htmlDate = "2020/03/21"
dateTokens = htmlDate.split('/')

pythonDate = date(dateTokens[0], dateTokens[1], dateTokens[2])
```

Here's the link to python datetime module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Comment: @bigshirtjonny I've added the example. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to convert the datetime attribute of your element to a datetime object and then compare.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Define yesterday datetime object
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)

# Convert attribute string of datetime to a datetime object
timeOfPost = 'Apr 1 2020  10:43AM'
datetime_timeOfPost = datetime.strptime(timeOfPost, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')

if (datetime_timeOfPost > yesterday):
    # do more stuff
```

You will need to modify how you convert since I don't know the value that you are seeing.  If you need help with datetime, you can find more info here:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html